# Per-mailbox IMAP settings in Exchange 2003 apply successfully but revert to server default

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

The title says most of it.

I have a Spiceworks mailbox that connects to our Exchange Server 2003 box via IMAP for receiving help desk issues. But for complicated reasons, I want it to receive those emails in text-only format.

So, I discovered that you can just go to:

- Exchange System Manager
- Administrative Groups
- First Administrative Group
- First Storage Group
- Mailbox Store
- Mailboxes
- Right-click the mailbox, Configure Exchange Features
- Edit the properties for IMAP
- Set that mailbox to only receive message bodies as plain text.

I click OK, then Next, it reports success, and I assume I'm done. But then when I go right back to where I was, I see that "Use protocol defaults" is still checked. Anyone have a clue why this would be?

Some other details: I'm logged in as Administrator when I do this. I can't change this setting for the entire IMAP virtual server because some regular users use it. I only have one IP address to play with, which means I can't create another IMAP virtual server. Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: this question was resolved by joeqwerty in the comments. If possible, I'd like the mods to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but it sounds a bit like it is inheriting the settings from the protocol setup.  It might be overriding the individual mailbox setups (though admittedly that seems counterintutive).

Comment: I don't see that functionality in ESM, but try setting it on the Exchange Features tab of the user account properties in ADUC.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! The ADUC Features tab is identical to the one from ESM, but from there the settings change sticks. That seems like a glitch on Microsoft's part, but at least it's figure out.